# Using awk to print 2nd column and rest of the text from #

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have these kind of lines in my config files,

```
bindsym $mod+F2 exec gnome-terminal #Open terminal 
bindsym $mod+p exec command /some/path"  #Popup Dictionary  
bindsym $mod+Mod1+l exec --no-startup-id /some/path/command #Dmenu for my books collection
bindsym Mod1+Control+b exec rxvt -e nnn #nnn file browser
```

I want to `awk` out the second column and things that are after the `#`. I am using `awk` as

```
awk '/bindsym/{print $2}' filename
```

I am not sure though how to get the text after the `#`.
The preferred output is, the keys and then the comment text as

```
$mod+F2 Open terminal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/^bindsym/ { key = $2; sub(".*#", ""); print key, $0 }' file
$mod+F2 Open terminal
$mod+p  Popup Dictionary
$mod+Mod1+l     Dmenu for my books collection
Mod1+Control+b  nnn file browser
```

This uses `awk` to first extract the second field on each line starting with `bindsym` into the variable `key`.  It then deletes everything up to and including the `#` on the line and prints `key` and what's remaining of the line with a tab as delimiter.

Alternative output formatting:

```
$ awk '/^bindsym/ { key = $2; sub(".*#", ""); printf("%-20s\t%-20s\n", key, $0) }' file
$mod+F2                 Open terminal
$mod+p                  Popup Dictionary
$mod+Mod1+l             Dmenu for my books collection
Mod1+Control+b          nnn file browser
```

The logic is the same, but the output allocates 20 characters for each of the two (left-justified) fields and puts a tab in-between them (for good measure).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `match()` function of GNU `awk` to match the part from `#` till the end of the line

```
awk '/bindsym/ && match($0,/#(.+)$/,arr){print $2, arr[1]}' filep
```

The `match()` function populates the array provided in the third argument with the matched pattern from the regex in the second argument.

on any POSIX `awk`, the third argument of `match()` is *not* supported, but couple of special variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` which mark the *start* and the *length* of the matched group. We use the `substr()` function on the current line to get the matched string

```
awk '/bindsym/ && match($0,/#(.+)$/){print $2, substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)}' file
```

To pretty-print the output, you can either use the `printf()` function as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do in `sed`; since your data isn't really field oriented Awk doesn't provide a huge benefit here:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]* //;s/ .*#//' inputfile
```

Translation:

```
s/^[^ ]* //
```

Delete everything up to and including the first space character.

```
s/ .*#//
```

Delete everything from the first (remaining) space character, up to the last `#` character on the line.

Answer (score -1):

```
Step1: count=`awk '{print NR}'|sed -n '$p' filename`

Step2:for ((i=1;i<=$count;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i && $0 ~ /^bindsym/{print $2}' filename; sed -n ""$i"s/.*#//p" filename; done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"


output
for ((i=1;i<=$count;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i && $0 ~ /^bindsym/{print $2}' filename; sed -n ""$i"s/.*#//p" filename; done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"

$mod+F2 Open terminal 
$mod+p Popup Dictionary  
$mod+Mod1+l Dmenu for my books collection
Mod1+Control+b nnn file browser
```

Comment: I'm assuming that there may be more than four lines in the input file. It is not clear what your first step would do other than print out the line number in the terminal.

Comment: Correcting the code

Comment: Corrected the code